# How to get the response if returned after the time out occurs

Tags: java, rest, http, apache-commons

I am consuming a REST web service from Java code using Apache commons HTTP client API. If no response returns within the socket timeout value configured in the connection manager parameters, socket time out exception occurs. In such cases as the thread returns the exception to the caller class, even if the REST service returns response few secs later, will be lost.

Is it possible to create a new thread which will still listen to the service even after the timeout and just logs the response, while the main thread returns the exception to the caller class?

Is there any better way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you are most likely looking for involves asynchronous requests. For every action you post you create a unique "job" id and with that a specific URL for the job status. After starting the job, you can then query on that specific job instance's status. For example:

1. POST to **/actions**
2. Returns `202 Accepted` & include a `Location` header to **/actions/results/1234**
3. Immediately GET **/actions/results/1234** to ascertain it's status.

   - If it returns a 2xx your job is done.
   - If it returns 404, wait 10 seconds (or whatever) and try again.
4. Once you are happy with the result, issue a DELETE to **/actions/results/1234** to clean up after yourself.

Of course you don't have to return 404 if the job is not done, there are other strategies for checking on the status - the key thing is that it's a subsequent call.

Comment: I want to achieve that functionality in synchronous call.

Comment: That very fact that you are suggesting a second thread implies an async call. That issue aside, you said you just want to log the result on the client - does that mean you don't need to make a decision based on the return value? As in the first call could fire and forget and your second thread can listen for and then log a result?